# How to solve the error 'Text scatter requires Text Analytics Toolbox'?

Tags: matlab

I ran a code with various functions. But the output was not complete and it showed error  'Text scatter requires Text Analytics Toolbox'. I think I have installed the complete MATLAB. Can anyone please tell me why do this error occur and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "complete" MATLAB, there are multiple toolboxes available with extend the functionality of MATLAB. An overview is given here: https://mathworks.com/products.html

When you log in with your mathworks account and go to https://mathworks.com/mwaccount/ you can see the products connected to your license.

I guess if you want to use that function, you have to buy it. Alternatively you can also look around for a substitute.